# how to select a non-drupal (souce db) database in a migrate module

Tags: 7, migrations

can i still use a db_select(); if my source database is a non-drupal site? how can the migrate module know what database im referring? i cant see any configuration for migrate module on how to change database selection.

```
$query = db_select('sourcedb.brands', 'b');
$query->addField('i1', 'foreign_key', 'foreign_key');
$query->addField('i1', 'locale', 'locale');
$query->addField('i1', 'content', 'brand_description');
$query->addField('b', 'name', 'brand_name');
$query->addField('b', 'owg_id', 'owg_id');
$query->join('sourcedb.i18n', 'i1', 'i1.foreign_key = b.id');
$query->condition('i1.locale', 'spa', '=');
$query->condition('i1.model', 'Brand', '=');
$query->condition('i1.field', 'description', '=');
$query->orderBy('i1.foreign_key', 'ASC');
```

is the "sourcedb" in 'sourcedb.brands' a keyword in drupal? or can i replace it directly with the table name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would probably be better if you looked at the [Feeds](http://drupal.org/project/feeds) module using the [Feeds Database](http://drupal.org/project/feeds_db) fetcher.

Comment: can feeds handle big data transfer?

Comment: Yes it can. And it can do all the drupal-type mapping for you.

Comment: HEy i have another problem, i cant see the list of databases in the Feeds Database module tab. check out my other question

Comment: hey @triskelion check out my other question sir http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/66955/cant-see-the-list-of-databases-in-feeds-database-module-ui-tab