# cant see the list of databases in Feeds Database module UI tab

Tags: 7, feeds

I have installed the feeds module and Feeds Database module so i can migrate contents inside my non drupal datase to a drupal 7 one. But i cant see the list of databases in the Feeds Database tab. Anyone can help?

Here's a code of my database in settings.php

```
$databases = array (
  'default' => 
  array (
    'default' => 
    array (
      'database' => 'karljay',
      'username' => 'root',
      'password' => '',
      'host' => 'localhost',
      'port' => '',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => '',
    ),

  ),
   'test' => 
  array (
    'test' => 
    array (
      'database' => 'joan',
      'username' => 'root',
      'password' => '',
      'host' => 'localhost',
      'port' => '',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => '',
    ),

  ),
);
```

this seems to be the right code cause i can see the test database now in the database's list in drupal but i have a database error when i import something using feeds.
and here's my error

[image]

and to add more details here's my query

```
$q=msyql_query("SELECT subject from forumthreads");
$result=mysql_fetch_array($q);
```

and here's my mapping

[image]

i only have one field cause this is a test if i can really use feeds to migrate many data from other database

Comment: so why is this downvoted? what's wrong?

Comment: Your comments table does not have a column named 'thread'. Double check the spelling, and the table structure.

Comment: but i did not map the comments yet. how come?

Comment: What tables are you mapping from:to in the two databases? Have you defined any other mappings then deleted them (If so it may be related to this [issue](http://drupal.org/node/1717264).

Comment: I just noticed the database definition **'test' => 
  array (
    'test' =>**. Change this to **'test' => 
  array (
    'default' =>**. (I know. Confusing!).

Comment: yes sir. i defined other mappings and deleted them. can it be the cause? if so what can i do to them? they are deleted already

Comment: i mapped the table forumthreads to table i dont know what table it is in drupal.

Comment: Read the issue about deleted mappings. You will have to do separate saves in each of your screens. It is a known issue with feeds, and has not been rectified.

Comment: The 'Query' box to configure the fetched is just expecting the query. No coding. Just enter the full SELECT query outputting the fields you need.

Comment: i decided to export my table in to a .csv file. is that ok? but still no luck in importing the datas. can you check again my next post. its about .csv. but i will try your last comment. removing my fetch_array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for this module is poor, but the solution is simple.

The module picks up the $databases array defined in your settings.php file. In most installations, only one database 'default' is defined. Use the format for 'default' and define a second database say 'test', listing the correct connection credentials. The 'test' database will show up in the drop down. The module removes 'default' from the list because it makes no sense to map a database to itself.

I think better documentation for Feeds Database is in order :). However, the core Database API can be configured for multiple databases. See [Database Configuration](http://drupal.org/node/310071).

Comment: hi again @Triskelion, i edited my post above cause i seem to have an error when i import the feeds. it seems to be a database problem so im guessing it's in the configuration of my added database. can you take a look if i did what you said correctly?

Comment: It appears to be correct from a Drupal standpoint. What is your error?

Comment: edited again, included my error